# ExtJs. Setting form values on load and change listeners

Tags: extjs

I need "good style" advice. I have a form which is populated from json. The code which populates the form is put inside render listener. The problem is, many form elements have change listeners, so when the form is populated these change listeners are triggered. I want to prevent this unwanted behavior.

```
// many form elements with change listeners come here

listeners:{
 render:function(){
    var frm=this.getForm();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'../handlers/instruct.handler.php?id='+id, 
        method:'POST',
        params:{action:'params'},
        success:function(result,request){
            json=Ext.decode(result.responseText,1);
            frm.setValues(json); // form population
                            // triggers change listeners 
        }
    });
 }
}
```

PS. I use ExtJs 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could suspend events on the fields:

```
var fields = form.getForm().getFields();
fields.each(function(f) {
    f.suspendEvents();
});
form.setValues(json);
fields.each(function(f) {
    f.resumeEvents();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, though two iterations for such a task do not seem optimal.

Comment: Whether you implement it at the app layer or even if it's done in the framework, you'll still need to iterate over the collection twice.

Comment: Another way is to use a global flag variable (or an object) and many "ifs" inside each change listener to check whether change event comes for the first time or not. It looks ugly, but wouldn't it be more optimal?

Comment: It would most likely be more optimal, but have you measured the performance? Premature optimization and all that. I doubt the difference has any significance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Besides, your solution is more concise and better in terms of maintenance. When the form gets bigger, all those "ifs" will become too heavy.